# displaying tags on a Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I remember seeing this widget on Wordpress which has sidebar displaying all of your tags from all your posts. When you click the tab it shows a list of posts with the tag you clicked on.

I can't seem to find it! Does anyone know a plugin I can use for this? or a way to do it?

Comment: You mean [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-tag-cloud-widget/screenshots/)?

Comment: That's the one! Thanks!